# How do I shorten my JQuery script for multiple accordion styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a WordPress theme with 4 accordion styles. I tried playing around with my code to make it shorter but nothing I do does the trick. Is there a way to shorten this? Your help will be appreciated!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style1 > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion-style1 > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if(jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style2 > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion-style2 > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if(jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style3 > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion-style3 > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if(jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style4 > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion-style4 > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if(jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michellecantin/4mYdn/

Comment: Also, if you're interested in performance, read this tutorial on CSS selector performance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

In general, it would be better for performance to apply the classes directly to the anchor elements, otherwise the browser has to check every anchor on the page to see what its parent nodes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('dl[class^=accordion-style] > dd').hide();
    jQuery('dl[class^=accordion-style] > dt > a').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().children("dd").slideUp();

        jQuery(this).parent().next("dd:hidden").slideDown();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mYdn/7/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the numbers after every class eg `<dl class="accordion-style">`

```
var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style > dd').hide();
jQuery('.accordion-style > dt > a').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).parents('.accordion-style').find('dd').slideUp();

    if (jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) 
       {
        jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
       }
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/4mYdn/2/

if you don't want to change class name you can do two things

1. `<dl class="accordion-style accordion-style1 ">` //add accordion-style before class name
2. Modify the code

   ```
   var allPanels = jQuery('dl[class^=accordion-style] > dd').hide();
   jQuery('dl[class^=accordion-style] > dt > a').on('click', function () {
       jQuery(this).parents('dl[class^=accordion-style]').find('dd').slideUp();

       if (jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
           jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
       }
       return false;
   });
   ```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/4mYdn/9/

**[Attribute start with selector ^](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

Comment: Exactly. Classes aren't made to be numbered so they can identify specific items.

Comment: I agree to @MildlyInteresting, but there're some scenarios where the developer can't just change the HTML markup, for whatever reason. So the solution proposed should fit what's there already, unless the markup is actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are all the functions the same except for one small difference? That would be the role of function parameters :)

```
function accordion(i) {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion-style'+i+' > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion-style'+i+' > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if(jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)accordion(i);
});
```

Comment: So, every time a new element is added, you need to change the script to fit the new number of elements? Not very clever.